# Count values after specific pattern in column occurs

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

My problem explained in Excel

[image]

Column A1:A22 have some binary numbers (0, 1). As you can see I highlighted numbers with GREEN fill color that match my pattern I want to find.
Column C5:C22 have formula as you can see in formula box, that CONCATENATE first four numbers ( A1:A4, A2:A5 etc..) in data set and check if it matches my pattern.
If this first four numbers match my pattern, I want Excel to count all NEXT numbers that are right after this pattern.

The biggest problem is that I can't do this this way because I have data set that have approximately 30.000 binary records in it, and my RAM memory can't handle that much of CONCANTENATE formula to count all NEXT values, after my pattern occurs.
I want someone to help me find other way without making HELPER columns, I want Excel formula, that in steps:

1. Search for pattern in data set..
2. IF pattern in data set matches my desired pattern, make AVERAGE of all values right after pattern occurs. So in example above my AVERAGE in cells C5:C22 = 0,66

I hope that I explain this in details so you know my problem, I need formula to do all the math stuff, I can't use helper columns like in example above.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A19:A22 also contains the desired pattern. That doesn't count?

Comment: Is VBA an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Concatenate once then Substitute *Pattern to find*

You can use `CONCATENATE` function in one cell, getting all the 1's and 0's into one cell.
Then `SUBSTITUTE` the *Pattern to find* with empty string `""`.
Then count how many *Patterns* were "Substitued" (Matched).

Like so:

[image]

### Formulas in cells

D5-Concat all: `=CONCAT(A1:A22)`
E5-Len all: `=LEN(D5)`
F5-Substitute: `=SUBSTITUTE(D5;Pattern;"")`
G5-Len after: `=LEN(F5)`
H5-Matches: `=(E5-G5)/PatternLen`

To get it into one cell:
`=(LEN(CONCAT(A1:A22))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(A1:A22);Pattern;"")))/PatternLen`

Comment: Can you refer to my question below, I would appreciate that, thanks very much in advance